# Better way to display NULL for datetime parameters in SSRS?

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, null

I have a bit of a pickle here.  Our users, and more specifically my boss thinks that showing "NULL" for dates, doesn't really make sense, because in actuality all dates are being considered when datetime is "NULL".  Is there any way to either change the word "NULL" to "ALL", or allow text in the Parameter default value?  When I try to enter some text like "" as the default value for the parameter, i get an error message saying it's not allowed, because it's not a date/time.  Any other ways of doing this?

**How it looks now:**

[image]

**What we would like it to look like:**

[image] or [image]

Or or there are any other ideas to indicate the idea that All dates are being considered, and not really "NULL"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any ability to customize the NULL label.

Probably your best workaround is to not allow nulls in the date parameter and have another parameter with a nicer label like "Select all results" then use this to filter whether you use the date parameter in your query or not.

Comment: update: i ended up just explaining "NULL" was the only way to go.  However I like your idea, so we may implement this in our other reports. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It's not good practice to show NULL without handling it properly, since NULL is 'value unknown' or 'no data'. So it can't be compared with any other value. For example if I don't know two persons DOB and I entered NULL in DOB value field which doesn't mean that both are having same DOB, just merely because both are having NULL values.

You can write script/expression in reporting to handle NULL values, parse date field if it's NULL then you can set to some default date value or something as per requirement.

Comment: While true, this has nothing to do with the question